# ElastAlert Security Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elastalert

I am using elastic search security.
Now I when I'm trying to use elastalert, I am getting following error:

```
elastalert.util.EAException: Error loading file example_rules/example_new_term.yaml: 
Error initializing rule Example new term rule: Error searching for existing terms: AuthenticationException
(401, 'security_exception', {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'security_exception',
 'reason': 'missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]', 'header': {'WWW-
Authenticate': 'Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"'}}], 'type': 
'security_exception', 'reason': 'missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]', 'header': 
{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"'}}, 'status': 401})
```

Can anyone help to skip this authentication?

Comment: You don't skip authentication if security is enabled, you need to configure elastalert to use the authentication. Set the variables `es_username` and `es_password` in your [`config.yaml`](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html#configuration).

Comment: @leandrojmp thanks. It worked after providing username and pass